# Why is my footer not sticking to the bottom?

Tags: html, css

```
body {
    background: #ffffff;
    color: #000;
    font-family: Verdana, Arial, Sans-Serif;
    font-size: 13px;
    text-align: center; /* IE 5 fix */
    line-height: 1.4;
height: 100%;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}

#container {
    width: 50%;
    background: #fff;
    border: none;
    color: #000000;
    margin: auto auto;
    padding: 20px;
    text-align: left; /* IE 5 fix */
overflow:auto;
padding-bottom: 180px
}

#wrap {
min-height: 100%;
}

#footer {
background: #000 url(images/cbf/foot.png) repeat;
border-top: solid 1px #000;
position: relative;
width:100%;
margin-top: -180px; /* negative value of footer height */
height: 180px;
clear:both;
}
```

Been working on it all day, maybe my eyes are just blind from being exhausted.

I have incorporated the wrap div on inside the body tags as well, I cleared my cached and tried Chrome and firefox as well.

Comment: "IE 5 fix" ?? in 2013?

Comment: the footer appears stuck to the bottom to me, can you define what you are looking for a bit more in detail

Comment: My guess is that your footer div is nested in a div that it shouldn't be nested in.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried adding in `bottom:0;` to the footer?

::EDIT:: Not too sure if you are talking about the whole footer or just the text. If you want the text at the bottom, give it a new div/class and set bottom:0; and it will put it down there for you. If you want the whole footer at the bottom, it's already there in my Firefox and Chrome.

::EDIT2::

```
#copyright { font: 11px Verdana, Arial, Sans-Serif; bottom: 0; padding: 10px 0 0 0; }
```

If you want the links on the bottom too, add them into the copyright div as well.

Here is your footer:

```
#footer {
background: #000 url(../../../images/cbf/foot.png) repeat;
border-top: solid 1px #000;
position: relative;
width:100%;
bottom: 0px;
margin-top: -180px; /* negative value of footer height */
height: 180px;
clear:both;
}
```

Comment: I did, but no change unless I change the position from relative to fixed. But, that makes the footer scroll when the browser is small.

Comment: Can you put it up so I can see what you're talking about?

Comment: It's live, it's using bottom: 0px; and I changed posistion:relative to fixed.

Comment: #copyright {
 font: 11px Verdana, Arial, Sans-Serif;
 bottom: 0;
 padding: 10px 0 0 0;
}
Add the div of copyright class to the links as well. Give that a go. Also return the footer to relative, but keep bottom:0;

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
#footer {
background: #000 url(images/cbf/foot.png) repeat;
border-top: solid 1px #000;
position: fixed;
bottom: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 180px;
clear: both;
}
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why are we adding position:fixed; ?

Comment: position:fixed; works, but when I minimize the browser the footer follows the scroller. Any work around?

Comment: Because fixed position along with bottom: 0; tells the browser to position that element at the bottom of the browser window no matter what.

Comment: So, no way to make it work with relative? Or keep it from scrolling? http://buildlinux.com/ uses the same forum software and their footer does not appear to be using bottom:0px; or position fixed.

Comment: Not sure I totally understand, but if you are looking to stick the footer at the bottom but also want it to disappear on scrolling, you will have to position it at the bottom of the content that is scrollable and inside the same element.

Answer (score 0):

i think problem with this class try below chanegs...i hope that should be work...

```
#copyright {
    border: 0 none;
    bottom: 0;
    font: 11px Verdana,Arial,Sans-Serif;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 10px 0 0;
    position: relative;
    top: 110px;
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you have height of your footer set to 180px which is creating the issue in your code `height: 180px`.

It should be `height: 60px`.